# Gtksourceviewmm syntax highlighting not working

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, gtkmm, gtksourceview

I'm trying to use the C++ wrapper gtksourceview, I made this a long time ago and I remember that it was working, but now everything works except the higlight syntax. And I'm not pretty sure what it is. I hope you can help me, I read a lot about this library on internet but I can find a solution. Here is a simple code. Thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include "twindow.h"
#include <iostream>

TWindow::TWindow() {

    add(m_SourceView);

    m_SourceView.set_size_request(640, 480);
    m_SourceView.set_show_line_numbers();
    m_SourceView.set_tab_width(4);
    m_SourceView.set_auto_indent();
    m_SourceView.set_show_right_margin();
    m_SourceView.set_right_margin_position(80);
    m_SourceView.set_highlight_current_line();
    m_SourceView.set_smart_home_end(gtksourceview::SOURCE_SMART_HOME_END_ALWAYS);

    gtksourceview::init ();

    Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceBuffer> buffer = m_SourceView.get_source_buffer () ;
    if (!buffer) {
        std::cerr << "gtksourceview::SourceView::get_source_buffer () failed" << std::endl ;
    }

    buffer->begin_not_undoable_action();
    buffer->set_text(Glib::file_get_contents("main.c"));
    buffer->end_not_undoable_action();

    buffer->set_highlight_syntax(true);

    Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceLanguageManager> language_manager = gtksourceview::SourceLanguageManager::create();
    Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceLanguage> language = gtksourceview::SourceLanguage::create();

    language = language_manager->get_language("c");

    buffer->set_language(language);

    show_all_children();
}
```

Comment: It's not the cause of any problem, but I can see that you are setting the language variable twice. The first call to gtksourceview::SourceLanguage::create() is not used because you then use get_language() instead.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that. But I still not found the solution. I was thinking that maybe it's something related to Windows configuration and not the code or libraries...

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use the c++ wrapper of gtksourceview, so I guess you want to use gtksourceviewmm.

Why you create the `LanguageManager`, you can use the default one.
If you using 3.2 of gtksourceviewmm, then look at the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceviewmm/3.2/classGsv_1_1LanguageManager.html#ac8c4832c34275d492de2a87e2a6cb61c).

You should also check out [this function](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceviewmm/3.2/classGsv_1_1LanguageManager.html#adf16d8729a9a604d0bac606cf058da0a).

So an example would look like;

```
Glib::ustring file_path = "/home/user/whatever/main.c";
Glib::RefPtr<Gsv::LanguageManager> language_manager = Gsv::LanguageManager::get_default();
Glib::RefPtr<Gsv::Language> language = language_manager->guess_language(file_path, Glib::ustring());
```

Another thing I want to mention is that you should create a buffer to show the content of the file, as in my projects I got a seg fault when I wanted to use `get_source_buffer()`, so it seems to be null by default.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gsv::Buffer> buffer = Gsv::Buffer::create(language);
buffer->set_text(Glib::get_file_contents(file_path));
this->m_SourceView.set_source_buffer(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm using the 2.4 on Windows, so I can't use those functions. About the buffer I already tried different ways including a similar you mentioned and nothing... I still believe that is something on Windows configuration.